# How to get rid of one footnote mark in Microsoft Word without automatic renumbering

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I would like to start my page numbers for Microsoft Word.  However, I would like it to start on page 2.  If I try and manually insert page numbers, say I put 1 on the second page, it labels ALL the footnotes 1.

If I say I want to give each page a number from the insert > page number page, it starts the page numbers on page 1, and there's apparently no way to update them to actually start on page 2.

Is there any way to fix this to START on page 2?
Aside: I work with LaTeX and am forced to use Word, which is completely inferior in literally every way... so this is maddening to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove header from the 2 first pages in document?](http://superuser.com/questions/452418/how-can-i-remove-header-from-the-2-first-pages-in-document)

Comment: @Raystafarian It is not a duplicate of that.  Please delete your comment.

Comment: Which edition/version of Word are you using?

Comment: @Yass Office 2010 Version 14.0.7143.5000

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you don't want a page number on the first page and you want the page number to start at 1 from the second page?

Comment: @Yass I don't want a page number on the Title page, and I don't want a page number on the Table of Contents page.  The BEST case scenario would allow me to manually input page numbers without Microsoft automatically relabeling each page.  For example, if I want to label page 5 by "34890" and page 6 by "3428", I should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps and you should be able to achieve what you want.

1. Navigate to the first page, click on the **Page Layout** tab, then **Breaks** and choose the **Next Page** option.
2. Next, staying on the first page, click anywhere in the footer to give it focus. On the **Design** tab, choose the **Different First Page** option. Repeat just this step for the second page (or more, depending on how many pages you want to exclude).
3. On the third page, if you want the page number to start at 1, select the **Page Number Format** option and type 0 in the **Start at** text box. The reason for this being that the previous page (second page) will be the start of the document after the page break. Because you selected the Different First Page option for the second page, it will not show a page number (even though it is assigned one by word).

The end result of the above will be two pages without a page number and the third page starting with a page number of 1.

---

If you want control of the page number on each page; every time you add a new page, you'll need to follow steps 1 and 2. It's kind of a tedious process, but it's the only way (that I know of) you'll have full manual control of each page.

Here's an example using the "New Page" page break (on the **Page Layout** tab) and the Different First Page option (on the **Design** tab):

[image: Page Number Control]

Comment: This does not allow me to manually change each page number without it automatically changing the rest of them.

Comment: You need to use additional page breaks. If you want the first two pages without numbers, the above method works. If you want other pages to have unique page numbers you need to make use of more page breaks.

Comment: Thank you.  However, that is completely ridiculous.  I shouldn't have to do all this work to change a simple number.

Comment: It is pretty terrible, I agree. There should definitely be an option to manually assign page numbers.